# Wait for sibling process in C

Tags: c, process, fork, wait, pause

While I was playing with C, and trying to learn more about processes, forks and wait, I've reached a problem where I'm not able to wait for a sibling process to finish until I can continue.

So, here's the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int processoDisplayLyric;
int processoDisplayGraph;
int processoTimer;

int main(){

    int numeroMusicaAtual = 0;
    int continueWorking = 0;
    int fathersPID = getpid();


    while(continueWorking == 0) {


        //Create graph process
        processoDisplayGraph = fork();

        if(processoDisplayGraph == 0){
            int work = 0;
            while(work == 0){
                pause();
            }
        }

        if(processoDisplayGraph != 0){

            //Create lyric process.
            processoDisplayLyric =  fork();

            if(processoDisplayLyric == 0){

                int work = 0;
                while(work == 0){
                    pause();
                }
            }

        }

        if(processoDisplayLyric != 0 && processoDisplayGraph != 0){

            //Create timer process.
            processoTimer = fork();

            if(processoTimer == 0){
                printf("I was created and i just want to wait for my brothers.\n");
            }

        }

        if(getpid() != fathersPID){

            wait(processoDisplayLyric);
            wait(processoDisplayGraph);
        }else{
            //It's the father.
            int child_status;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                pid_t wpid = waitpid(processoDisplayLyric, &child_status, 0);
                if (WIFEXITED(child_status))
                    printf("Saw %d done with %d\n", wpid, WEXITSTATUS(child_status));
                else
                    printf("Child %d terminated abnormally\n", wpid);
            }
        }

        numeroMusicaAtual++;
    }

}
```

The thing is: processDisplayLyric, processDisplayGraph and processTimer are created, BUT, the Timer DOESN'T wait for the other two to finish (something that should never happen!!!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under standard POSIX, only a parent process can wait for its (immediate) children to die.

- Sibling processes cannot wait for other sibling processes to die.
- Child processes cannot wait for parent processes to die.
- A grandparent process cannot wait for grandchildren to die.

There are ways to detect whether a parent process is dead (the result of `getppid()` is `1`, or if you recorded the original PPID, then signalling it fails).  You can find out if you could signal a known PID — and if it doesn't exist, you can't.  There may be some alternatives on some platforms using other APIs.  But there's no general analogy to `wait()` for siblings or parents (or any other related process) — only children can be waited for.

Note that recent versions of Linux (since kernel 3.4) have the [`prctl()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) system call.  The `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` option allows a process other than the system process (PID 1 usually) to collect the status information of dead children in its process hierarchy.  That's still not collecting sibling processes; it is only able to collect children, grandchildren, great-grandchildren, and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!